# Pasar datos de un arraylist desde un jframe a un jdialog

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

Como puedo hacer para pasar los datos de un `ArrayList` situado en un `JFrame` a otra ventana con `JDialog`

en la ventana principal he creado los `ArrayList` y ahora tengo que mostrar los datos en un `JDialog` la clase principal con es la siguiente

```
public class Principal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ArrayList<Paciente> pacientes = new ArrayList<Paciente>();

    public Principal() {
        initComponents();
        this.setTitle("Clinica Trassierra - Menú Principal");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        iniciarPacientes();
        iniciarDoctores();
    }

    public void iniciarPacientes() {
        int i;
        int[] codpaciente = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
        String[] nombrepac = {"Luisa Romero", "Juan Madrid", "Rocio Lopez", "Carmen Pérez", "Pedro García", "Ana Martos", "Carlos Sevilla", "María Vega"};
        int[] edad = {41, 9, 5, 47, 52, 38, 23, 3};
    }

    public void iniciarDoctores() {
        int i;
        int[] codigo = {1,2,3,4,5};
        String[] nombredoctor = {"Elena Diaz Lopez","Juan Ruiz Luque","Marta Jaén García","Ana Perez Martin","José Guerrero Castro"};
        String[] especialidad = {"Medicina General","Medicina General","Pediatria","Pediatria","Cirugia"};

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        gestion = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        GestionarCitas = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        Salir = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        informe = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        citasPordoctor = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/logoclinica.jpg"))); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(116, 116, 116)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(122, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(87, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(81, 81, 81))
        );

        jMenuBar1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        gestion.setText("Gestión");

        GestionarCitas.setText("Gestionar Citas");
        GestionarCitas.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                GestionarCitasActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        gestion.add(GestionarCitas);

        Salir.setText("Salir");
        Salir.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                SalirActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        gestion.add(Salir);

        jMenuBar1.add(gestion);

        informe.setText("Informes");

        citasPordoctor.setText("Citas por Doctor");
        informe.add(citasPordoctor);

        jMenuBar1.add(informe);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void GestionarCitasActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        CitaPaciente citapaciente = new CitaPaciente(this, true);
        citapaciente.setVisible(true);
    }                                              

    private void SalirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
       System.exit(0);
    }                                     

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Principal().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem GestionarCitas;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem Salir;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem citasPordoctor;
    private javax.swing.JMenu gestion;
    private javax.swing.JMenu informe;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Ahora tengo que solicitar los datos desde este `JDialog`

```
public class CitaPaciente extends javax.swing.JDialog {
  DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();

  public CitaPaciente(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  }

  /**
   * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
   * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
   * regenerated by the Form Editor.
   */
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
   private void initComponents() {
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jSpinner1 = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        nombrePaciente = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        edad = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cobEspecialidad = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cobDoctor = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        btnAgregarCita = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tablaCitas = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnCerrar = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Datos del Paciente"));

        jLabel3.setText("Código del paceinte: ");
        jLabel4.setText("Nombre y Apellido: ");          nombrePaciente.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

        jLabel5.setText("Edad: ");

        edad.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addComponent(jSpinner1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(nombrePaciente, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 154, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(edad, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(edad, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(jSpinner1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addComponent(nombrePaciente, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/logoclinicapeq.jpg"))); // NOI18N

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Clinica Trassierra - Gestion de Citas de Pacientes");

        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Datos de la Cita"));

        jLabel6.setText("Especialidad:");

        cobEspecialidad.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        jLabel7.setText("Dotor/a");

        cobDoctor.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        btnAgregarCita.setText("AgregarCita");

        jLabel8.setText("Fecha y Hora: ");

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        jLabel9.setText("Numero de Consulta:");

        jLabel10.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel6)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(cobEspecialidad, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 170, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel8)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 56, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(cobDoctor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 180, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                        .addComponent(btnAgregarCita, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 119, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel9)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(33, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addComponent(cobEspecialidad, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                    .addComponent(cobDoctor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnAgregarCita, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel9))
                    .addComponent(jLabel10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(37, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        tablaCitas.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(tablaCitas);

        jButton1.setText("Eliminar Cita");

        btnCerrar.setText("CERRAR");
        btnCerrar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnCerrarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(45, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 169, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(49, 49, 49)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 341, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(228, 228, 228))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 503, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(55, 55, 55)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 153, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(btnCerrar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 153, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 59, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 246, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 54, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(53, 53, 53)
                        .addComponent(btnCerrar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnCerrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
       dispose();
    }                                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CitaPaciente.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CitaPaciente.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CitaPaciente.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CitaPaciente.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the dialog */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                CitaPaciente dialog = new CitaPaciente(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
                dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnAgregarCita;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnCerrar;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> cobDoctor;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> cobEspecialidad;
    private javax.swing.JLabel edad;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JSpinner jSpinner1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel nombrePaciente;
    private javax.swing.JTable tablaCitas;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Es ahi donde me pierdo, como puedo hacer para mandar datos de un `JFrame` a un `JDialog`, he estado mirando y hay que modificar el constructor del `JDialog` para que reciba el `ArrayList`, pero no se como cargar el `ArrayList` en el constructor del `JDialog`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes intentar inyectar el ArrayList al momento de la construccion del JDialog, seria de la siguiente manera

```
private void GestionarCitasActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        CitaPaciente citapaciente = new CitaPaciente(this, true,this.pacientes );
        citapaciente.setVisible(true);
}
```

Y en el constructor y dentro de la clase CitaPaciente

```
public class CitaPaciente extends javax.swing.JDialog{
//Declaramos el atributo de la lista de paciente 
ArrayList<Paciente> pacientes;
public CitaPaciente(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal,ArrayList<Paciente> pacientes) {
    super(parent, modal);
    this.pacientes = pacientes;
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  }
}
```

De esta manera manera el ArrayList dentro de la clase principal esta siendo apuntado por el ArrayList de la clase CitaPaciente, por lo que es la misma información y la misma localidad de memoria.

Otra opción es hacer que tu ArrayList sea estatico.

```
public static ArrayList<Paciente> pacientes = new ArrayList<Paciente>();
```

Para acceder dentro del JDialog seria

```
public class CitaPaciente extends javax.swing.JDialog{
    private void algunMetodoDondeNecesitesElArrayList(){
        Principal.pacientes.add(new Paciente());
    }
}
```

No lo recomiendo, al menos que quieras que todas las clases tengan acceso a el y necesites que lo modifiquen.